# Changing local variables in the parent scope of a script block

Tags: powershell

I want to supply a script block as argument to a function. This script block should change a local variable in the parent, using one of its arguments for it. The situation is as follows:

```
## function definition
function test {
    param( [scriptblock]$sb ) 
    $sb.Invoke( 5 )
}

## this is my local variable
$localVariable = 10

## update the local variable using a script block
test( { param( $m ) write-host "local: $localVariable"; $localVariable += 5 } )
```

The invocation seems to be able to see the local variable (it prints 10), but the addition is not propagated to the parent scope. How can this be done? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the parent scope is `script` or `global` scope, you can do this:

```
test { param( $m ) write-host "local: $localVariable"; $script:localVariable += 5 }
```

For arbitrary parent scopes try this:

```
test { param( $m ) write-host "local: $localVariable"; Set-Variable -Scope 1 -Name localVariable -Value ($localVariable += 5) }
```

You may need to fiddle with the scope argument.  When I execute this from the console, I had to use 2 to get it change $localVariable as a global.

Comment: Okay, I should have been more precise. The function is actually a ScriptMethod of a custom class defined in another module and the method invocation is in a script... Can your solution be adaptet to this situation?